# How can I sum the values on Power BI Deneb?

Tags: charts, powerbi, bar-chart, deneb

I have a table with the values that I want to display on Power BI Deneb Bar chart.

| LossReason | PrimaryQuantityLoss |
| --- | --- |
| Chupados | 1 |
| Generic Terminate | 18530 |
| Generic Terminate | 929 |
| Generic Terminate | 980 |
| Leitosas | 1 |
| Manchas | 1 |

But the values are not aggregating [Values stacked one above the others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMJQw.png) , the value displayed should be 20.439 instead of 18530/929/980 separated on the same bar.

I'm using the following specification:

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  
  "layer":[{
      "mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "black", "xOffset": 8},
        "encoding": {
          "text": {"field": "PrimaryQuantityLoss", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }]
  ,
  
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "PrimaryQuantityLoss",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "LossReason",
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do an aggregate by sum, but doesn't worked.

Comment: Hello @Faria, values are not aggregating because you added `LossReason` in Y axis. It like you're doing `Group By`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"PrimaryQuantityLoss"` to `"Sum of PrimaryQuantityLoss"`. As below, we can do it manually.

---

(1) Go to Visualizations > Values > "PrimaryQuantityLoss" and select `Sum`.

[image]

(2) Then a message window will appear to set the Field. Select `Sum of PrimaryQuantityLoss` as newly assigned field.

[image]

(3) Done. You will notice that the text encoding and the x-field are both renewed.

[image]

New specification is:

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},

  "layer":[{
      "mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "black", "xOffset": 8},
        "encoding": {
          "text": {"field": "Sum of PrimaryQuantityLoss", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }]
  ,

  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Sum of PrimaryQuantityLoss",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "LossReason",
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  }
}
```